# Optimizing jquery addclass / removeclass

Tags: jquery

So basically im stuck here with alot of code because I have no idea how to write it in an optimized manner.

Many times I encounter moments where I want an element (A) to be clickable and by doing so it adds various classes. Then when I click on another element (B) it undos all previous classes from click A.

I think you get a better idea of my problem when you see what mess I wrote. It works perfectly but im perfectly aware that this is suboptimal:

What am I doing wrong? How do I write those things in a better way?

```
 $(".home").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("item-active");
        $(".block-1").toggleClass("blocks");
        $(".b1").toggleClass("blockss");


        $(".block-2").removeClass("blocks");
        $(".b2").removeClass("blockss");
        $(".products").removeClass("item-active");
        $(".block-3").removeClass("blocks");
        $(".b3").removeClass("blockss");
        $(".hair-expert").removeClass("item-active");
        $(".block-4").removeClass("blocks");
        $(".b4").removeClass("blockss");
        $(".for-professionals").removeClass("item-active");
        $(".an1").removeClass("an1-default");

    });
    $(".products").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("item-active");
        $(".block-2").toggleClass("blocks");
        $(".b2").toggleClass("blockss");
        $(".an1").addClass("an1-default");

        $(".block-1").removeClass("blocks");
        $(".b1").removeClass("blockss");
        $(".home").removeClass("item-active");
        $(".block-3").removeClass("blocks");
        $(".b3").removeClass("blockss");
        $(".hair-expert").removeClass("item-active");
        $(".block-4").removeClass("blocks");
        $(".b4").removeClass("blockss");
        $(".for-professionals").removeClass("item-active");

    });
    $(".hair-expert").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("item-active");
        $(".block-3").toggleClass("blocks");
        $(".b3").toggleClass("blockss");

        $(".block-1").removeClass("blocks");
        $(".b1").removeClass("blockss");
        $(".home").removeClass("item-active");
        $(".block-2").removeClass("blocks");
        $(".b2").removeClass("blockss");
        $(".products").removeClass("item-active");
        $(".block-4").removeClass("blocks");
        $(".b4").removeClass("blockss");
        $(".for-professionals").removeClass("item-active");
        $(".an1").removeClass("an1-default");


    });
    $(".for-professionals").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("item-active");
        $(".block-4").toggleClass("blocks");
        $(".b4").toggleClass("blockss");

        $(".block-1").removeClass("blocks");
        $(".b1").removeClass("blockss");
        $(".home").removeClass("item-active");
        $(".block-2").removeClass("blocks");
        $(".b2").removeClass("blockss");
        $(".products").removeClass("item-active");
        $(".block-3").removeClass("blocks");
        $(".b3").removeClass("blockss");
        $(".hair-expert").removeClass("item-active");
        $(".an1").removeClass("an1-default");

    });
```

**Added JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wt6mkkng/8/**

Comment: Please provide relevant HTML, and/or setup fiddle....

Comment: @nevermind ok hang on. Give me 5 minutes

Comment: Set a base class depending on the button clicked and style elements accordingly. That way this all goes into CSS and you won't need all that jQuery code.

Comment: @nevermind http://jsfiddle.net/wt6mkkng/8/

Comment: @cschuff check out my jsfiddle

Comment: @cschuff can you show me a small example of how you mean that with base class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wt6mkkng/22/)); it assumes that the `li`'s are in the same order as the `block-1`, `block-2`, etc:

```
$('nav li').on('click', function () {
    var $active = $(this),
        // the .index() function returns a zero-based index of the li count
        // (if you click on the second li, the index will return as 1; so it goes 0.. 1.. 2.., etc)
        activeIndex = $active.index();
    // make the clicked LI active
    $active.addClass('item-active')
        // find the adjacent LI's and remove the active class
        .siblings()
        .removeClass('item-active');

    // cycle through each div block; this is using the attribute selector since
    // the divs only have "block-1", "block-2" as filenames. This might be easier to
    // read and understand if every block-# div also had a similar class name like "main-block"
    // then you could just use $('.main-block').each....
    $('div[class*="block-"]').each(function (i) {
        // make sure to include the "i" parameter in the function above; it
        // contains the current zero-based index of the element

        var $block = $(this)
            // add the "blocks" class if the block div index matches the active LI index
            // otherwise remove the "blocks" class. That's why toggleClass works nicely here
            .toggleClass('blocks', i === activeIndex)
            // find the "b1", "b2" divs inside the block; children() finds all immediate
            // children, so it could also return a <span> or <a> if it was there
            .children()
            // add "blockss" class if the block div index matches the active LI index
            // same as above
            .toggleClass('blockss', i === activeIndex);

        // Add animation class to the div
        // this one is a bit more tricky since the "an1-default" class is only added
        // when the block is active; it might be better to move this outside
        // of this loop and just look for $('.an1.blockss') to add/remove the animation class
        if (activeIndex === 1) {
            $('.an1').addClass('an1-default');
        } else {
            $('.an1').removeClass('an1-default');
        }

    });

    // add/remove classes on the links inside the clicked menu item
    $active.find('a').addClass('unfocus-list');
    $active.siblings().find('a').removeClass('unfocus-list');

    // I'm not sure what to do with this...
    // the content is visible on page load
    // but clicking on ANY link will remove it, and it won't
    // ever come back unless you reload the page - yuck
    $(".content").addClass("content-removed");

});
```

Comment: thank you so much but im really really interested in how your code works.For example siblings and children, activeIndex. I really want to learn. By the way, when clicking the second time on the same li the purple menu items should go away with the content text reappearing.

Comment: @Mottie, great! Had similar solution, but you didn't even touched HTML code... i've added data attributes to divs. :)

Comment: @nevermind please go ahead and add it since Steve is asking to learn, it's better to see different approaches :) I also would recommend modifying the HTML to make your life, and the coding a little easier.

Comment: Yeah, I just closed mine out - I added attributes to the HTML. Yours is much more succinct. I thought of using "index()", dang.. I should of went downt that route. Yeah, yours is nice.

Comment: @Steve, yes, it is by far best solution... however, i'll post mine... little easier approach.... :)

Comment: I added an explanation to my scripting. Yeah, it's a little convulted. As I said before, it would be better to modify the HTML to make this coding easier and easier to understand.

Comment: If you didn't understand something, make sure to read up on the function in the jQuery docs, like [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

Comment: @Mottie it seems your code conflicts with my if statements because the menu doesnt clode when clicked again but I think if I study your code I can integrate that function and remove the if statements right?

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer once again with that bit of extra code at the bottom. Basically I integrated it into the main block of code. Is the `.content` always going to be hidden?

Comment: @Mottie only hidden when a menu is active. Then becomes visible again when menus are inactive. Im studying your code and just noticed how pathetic my methods were

Comment: @Mottie both methods seem interesting. Yours and neverminds.  What are the clear advantages and disadvantages of both methods?

Comment: Don't think like that. I think the best way to learn is from just  writing code and also seeing code that others have written. I would recommend looking at some of the other jQuery menu plugins and see how they do it.

Comment: Honestly, I think the best code is the code you understand, and can maintain. I bet a year from now you'll look at the code I wrote and think to yourself, I would do that different, or make this more efficient. The differences in the coding style, at least for a simple menu, are negligible so there isn't really a advantage/disadvantage issue here.

Comment: @Mottie check my old jsfiddle and click on a link twice. You will see if the same link is clicked twice then the content appears again and the link becomes inactive. The functionality seems to be missing in your above example.

Comment: @mottie activeIndex === 0 means the item is inactive right?

Comment: ok I used toggleClass instead of addclass but not working as expected http://jsfiddle.net/wt6mkkng/30/ :D. Still studying your code

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten things up a bit like so, then perhaps see what else you can shore up in terms of reducing code. removeClass accepts a space-delimited list of the class names to remove.

$(".block-2 .block-3 .block-4").removeClass("blocks");

Comment: I could be incorrect, but when looking at code in which performance isn't a huge issue. For instance, in this case - I'd look to reduce code clutter and I like to get nifty in trying to reduce code as much as possible. Think about, what if you had to add a new menu item, or edit it in general.. how much upkeep is that?

Comment: that is so true which is why im abit upset about the methods I use. Someone told me to use loops which im unfamiliar with. Others tell me other things. Did you see my JSfiddle?

Comment: Give me a few minutes, coding something up for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('nav ul li').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('item-active'); //needed for content removal (your code at the //bottom)
     $(this).siblings().removeClass('item-active');
    id=$(this).attr('class'); // get class 
 id = id.split(" "); //since we add class, split it and get first part
if( id[0]== "products") {
   $(".an1").addClass("an1-default");
} else {
                 $(".an1").removeClass("an1-default");
            }    


   $( "div" ).each(function() {  //loop thourough divs
        if($(this).data('id')==id[0]) { //if div is related to nav link, via data //attribute, do what should be done
           // console.log($(this).html());
            $(this).toggleClass("blocks");
        $(this).children().toggleClass("blockss");
             $(this).siblings().removeClass("blocks");
        $(this).siblings().children().removeClass("blockss");
        }

}); 

});
```

Assuming that you can change html, add html5 attribute data to divs, like this:

```
 <div class="block-1" data-id="home">
  <div class="b1 "><a href="#">XX</a></div>
   <div class="b1"><a href="#">XX</a></div>
    <div class="b1"><a href="#">XX</a></div>
    <div class="b1"><a href="#">XX</a></div>
  </div>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wt6mkkng/19/

Comment: so what are the advantages of your method and Motties method? I see you use data ids. How big is support for data-ids?

Comment: Advantages related to your approach? Less coding, no repetition... My approach is simpler, Mottie's is better, smarter :)  In cases like this (show/hide block on nav link click) - i like to connect nav link and related div/block somehow, so i can avoid hard coding, for every link/block, and i like to make HTML as simple as possible (with nice id/class names), to make life easier. :) Basically, there is one scheme: show one, hide the rest (usually siblings!), and there could be different approaches... Regarding second question: http://caniuse.com/#feat=dataset

Comment: How come his is better? you mean in regards to performance or in what way?

Comment: He found way to make it, WITHOUT changing of your HTML. And, yes, he targeted just divs with 'block-' classes...so, i guess it could be little faster?

Comment: makes sense. Im studying his code then I will study your code.

Comment: if you check out my if statement for the content removal when an item is clicked. Is this method ok or bad?

Comment: Actually, i don't see better solution. It is ok to me... :)

Comment: Hehe :) I just started to understand motties solution and did some change to the html and css. Have a look http://jsfiddle.net/wt6mkkng/25/